# Hitting system limits with my testClass

Tags: unit-test, rest, limits, httpcalloutmock

I have two classes. One exposed as a REST service. Lets call this class "thefeeder". This class calls another class which implements Queueable  interface. Lets call this class "theQueue".

I wrote a test class for "thefeeder". I created a [Mock](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_testing.htm) just like the docs ask us to.

Here is my actual code for the Mock and the Testclass.

```
@isTest
private class TestDataFeeder {

    @isTest 
    static void test_method_one() 
    {
    DataFeederMock ms = new DataFeederMock(200);
      Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, ms);
      HttpResponse res = ms.respond(new HttpRequest());
        String contentType = res.getHeader('Content-Type');
        System.assert(contentType == 'application/json');
        System.assertEquals(200, res.getStatusCode());
    }
}

@isTest
public class DataFeederMock implements HttpCalloutMock {

    protected Integer code;
    protected String status;
    protected String body;
    protected String jsonStr;

    public DataFeederMock(Integer code) 
    {
        jsonStr = '[{"Case": {"CaseId": -100,"CaseCategory": "Delivery"}]';
        String badJsonStr = '{"NULL":"NULL"}';
        this.code = code;
        if(code == 200)
        {
            DataFeeder.feeder(jsonStr);
            this.body = '{"result": "success",   "reason": "all done"}';
        }
        else{
            DataFeeder.feeder(badJsonStr);
            this.body = '{"result": "failure",   "reason": "mock failure"}';
        }
    }

    public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {

        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setBody(this.body);
        res.setStatusCode(this.code);
        return res;
    }
}
```

The pseudo-code for my class looks something like this:

```
    public class DataQueue implements Queueable 
{
    public class DataQueueException extends Exception{}
    public CaseContainer.RootObject caseObj;
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) 
    {
        Savepoint sp1 = Database.setSavepoint();
        String ApexJobId = context.getJobId();
        Boolean isServiceCase = false;
        Date dt;
        try
        {
            if(caseObj == null)
            {
                throw new DataQueueException('Case Object not Correctly Populated!');
            }
            else
            {
                //Insert Records to various objects.
                Case = new Case();
                Case.CustomField1 = caseObj.CustomField1;
                Case.Subject = caseObj.Subject;
                insert Case;
            }
    }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Database.rollback(sp1);
        }
    }
}
```

With these pieces in place, I faced my first exception:
**System.Limits exception - Too many queued jobs.**

So I modified the feeder. This is my modified feeder class.

```
    @RestResource(urlMapping='/DataFeeder/*')
global with sharing class DataFeeder 
{
    @HttpPost
    global static void feeder(string jsonStr)
    {
        if(! Test.isRunningTest())
        {
         RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
         jsonStr = RestContext.request.requestBody.toString();
        }

        system.debug('RequestBody: ' + jsonStr);

        integer totalQueueableJobs = System.Limits.getLimitQueueableJobs();
        integer currentQueueableJobs = 0;
        //Try the list over here.
        List<CaseContainer.RootObject> rootlist = new List<CaseContainer.RootObject>();
        try{    
            rootlist = (List<CaseContainer.RootObject>) JSON.deserialize(jsonStr, List<CaseContainer.RootObject>.class);    
            for(Object root:rootlist)
            {
                CaseContainer.RootObject root2 = (CaseContainer.RootObject) root;
                system.debug('root'+root2);
                if(currentQueueableJobs < totalQueueableJobs)
                {
                    if(! Test.isRunningTest()) **//Gave a system.limit exception for too many queued jobs.**
                    {
                        DataQueue mdq = new DataQueue();
                        mdq.caseObj = root2;
                        Id jobId = System.enqueueJob(mdq);
                        System.Debug(jobId);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                  if(Test.isRunningTest())
                {
                    DataFeederMock msd = new DataFeederMock(100);
                    RestContext.response.responseBody =msd.respond(new HttpRequest()).getBodyAsBlob();
                }   
                else{
                    //return '{"result":"failure","reason":"exceeding apex limitation!"}';
                    RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('{"result":"failure","reason":"exceeding apex limitation!"}');
                    }
                }

                currentQueueableJobs = System.Limits.getQueueableJobs();
            }

            if(Test.isRunningTest())
            {
                    DataFeederMock msd = new DataFeederMock(200);
                    RestContext.response.responseBody =msd.respond(new HttpRequest()).getBodyAsBlob();
            }   
            //return '{"result":"success","reason":"all done"}';
            RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('{"result":"success","reason":"all done"}');
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.Debug(ex.getMessage());
            RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('{"result":"failure","reason":"' + ex.getMessage() +'"}');        
        }
    }
}
```

After this change, I have got another system.limits exception. This time the exception is **Maximum Stack Depth reached.**

What should I do next?

Comment: look at the debug log and see what is being invoked recursively.